Infer typings of Record
I'm currently using Typescript to strongly-type names and values for feature flags in our application. eg:
type FeatureFlagName = 'foo' | 'bar';

type FeatureFlags = Record<FeatureFlagName, boolean>;

const featureFlagDefaults: FeatureFlags = {
  'foo': false,
  'bar': false,
};

This has worked fine so far to ensure if you use featureFlagDefaults.foo, it expects it to be a boolean.
Now, I need to add a new feature flag, but its default value is a number. I can add it as follows:
type FeatureFlagName = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'another';

type FeatureFlags = Record<FeatureFlagName, boolean | number>;

const featureFlagDefaults: FeatureFlags = {
  'foo': false,
  'bar': false,
  'another': 10,
};

The problem, however, is that it doesn't know if the value for any flag is boolean or number. I'm looking for a way to infer the type somehow. How can I do that so that when featureFlagDefaults.foo is referenced in code, it will see it as a boolean and when featureFlagDefaults.another is referenced in code, it will see it as a number?

Why not define the type as {foo: boolean, bar: boolean, another: number}?

You can maintain the flag names in individual unions, grouped by their associated type, then intersect Records of them… like this. If that meets your needs, I can write an answer from it — if not, what did I miss?

@jsejcksn Thanks! How would I be able to correctly type a function that gets the flag value? getFlagValue: (flagName: FeatureFlagName) => ???;

^ @mellis481 You'd use a constrained generic type parameter like this — but that's not part of your question…

It's not clear from this question why you need Record or FeatureFlagName at all. If you want to represent a relationship between keys and values, just use an interface as shown in this playground link (which is the same as the top comment by @Dogbert). If that meets your needs someone can write an answer (but it's a very basic thing for TS, so I'm confused why this wouldn't already be the approach taken here). If not, please [edit] to clarify what you're doing and why the obvious type approach doesn't work for you.

Instead of the utility type Record, use an Interface with an index signature and a conditional type constraint on the value.
type FeatureFlagName = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'another';

type FeatureFlags = {
   [key in FeatureFlagName]: key extends 'another' ? number : boolean;
};

const featureFlagDefaults: FeatureFlags = {
   'foo': false,
   'bar': false,
   'another': 10,
};


You can use satisfies operator if you are using TS 4.9 or later:
type FeatureFlags = Record<FeatureFlagName, boolean | number>;

const featureFlagDefaults = {
  'foo': false,
  'bar': false,
  'another': 10,
} satisfies FeatureFlags;


Just cast it as const like this:
const featureFlagDefaults = {
  'foo': false,
  'bar': false,
  'another': 10,
} as const

This tells typescript that no keys or values will change, even more so than originally defining it as a const variable. This will give you more strict typing.
Additionally, you can use this to type a larger featureFlag object, not just the default values:
type FixedBoolean<X extends object> = {
    [K in keyof X]: X[K] extends false ? boolean : X[K] extends true ? boolean : X[K]
}

const featureFlagDefaults = {
  'foo': false,
  'bar': false,
  'another': 10,
}

let x: FixedBoolean<typeof featureFlagDefaults> = {}


What is the type of e.g. foo here? Hint: it's not boolean. Also, why would you expect a feature flag to be set at compile time?

...ignoring for a minute the needless and unwarranted personal jab, why would OP need any of this instead of the obvious simple approach suggested by jcalz in the comments on the question? As for the feature flag thing, the entire point of feature flags is decoupling releases of features from deployments of code, having them be set at compile time just recouples them. If OP didn't intend the semantics of feature flags, then why did they name it that? This could have been a good opportunity to ask a clarifying question of the OP. Given all of that, what is the point of adding as const?
